# How to create indexed values for each stock price in R?

Tags: r

so I've been trying to create a indexed stock chart as a part of a project while learning R. Now I'd like to do the same with indexed values, so I want to create a vector of indexed values for each of my stocks. I tried the following:

```
indeksih <- apply(kombo, huhtamaki, FUN = huhtamaki/huhtamaki[1])
```

however this gives me *Error in Ops.data.frame(huhtamaki, huhtamaki[1]) : 
  ‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames*

This is how my data looks like:

```
 head(kombo)

Date             Huhtamaki Sampo  Kone
1 2019-12-30     41.38     38.91  58.28
2 2019-12-27     41.84     39.07  59.14
3 2019-12-23     41.66     39.13  59.02
4 2019-12-20     41.57     39.22  59.06
5 2019-12-19     40.69     38.99  58.32
6 2019-12-18     40.74     38.41  57.68
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `indexksi <- kombo$Huhtamaki/kombo$Huhtamaki[1]`

Comment: You want the values in the column to be divided by the first value in the column?

Answer (score 0):

Simply dividing the column by the first element of the column:

```
kombo[,"Huhtamaki"]/kombo[1, "Huhtamaki"]
```

If you want to do it on many columns a data.table approach can be useful

```
library(data.table)
setDT(kombo)
kombo[,lapply(.SD, function(x) x/x[1]), .SDcols = names(kombo[, -"date"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
indexksi <- kombo$Huhtamaki/kombo$Huhtamaki[1]
```